# display menu with out list tags

Tags: theme-development

Is there a way I can display a menu in my theme that isn't formatted in a list? i just want to display the `<a>` tags without the `<li>` tags.

is this possible?

theme file:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'navigation' ) ); ?>
```

functions.php:

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array('navigation' => __( 'Main Nav' )));
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**Edit:** see my answer below, found on Stack Overflow

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what i'll need to do is look at a customized menu walker, as suggested at this thread over on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003918/editting-wp-nav-menu-so-it-prints-divs-instead-of-lis

From there, looking at suggestions I found:

http://www.mattvarone.com/wordpress/cleaner-output-for-wp_nav_menu/

That's solved this perfectly!